# Updating join table for multiple instances of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make an automatch system, but the below code only inserts them into the "matches" table. I want it to insert both player IDs into the matches_users join table, how to correct this? Thanks!

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

# Associations
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
belongs_to :user

def initialize_match
    return false unless empty?
    players = match_players
    with_lock do
      # Makes transaction
      self.user_1 = players[0].id
      self.user_2 = players[1].id
      finished = false
      save!
    end    
end

def match_players
    users = User.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
end
```

And my user class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Associations
has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
```

Comment: I think you need to remove `belongs_to :user` from Match class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associations are not saved because you have not assigned the `users` attribute.

```
with_lock do
      # Makes transaction
      self.user_1 = players[0].id  # Remove this if user_1 is not an attribute of Match
      self.user_2 = players[1].id  # Remove this if user_2 is not an attribute of Match
      users = []
      users << User.find(players[0].id))
      users << User.find(players[1].id))
      self.users = users
      finished = false
      save!
end
```

To delete the Users data (in the join table), when delete a Match, use `:dependent` attribute.

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

   # use this if you using has_many :through
   # In this method, you should use Match.destroy(id) instead of Match.delete(id)

   has_many :users, through: :MatchUsers, :dependent => :destroy

   # use this if you are using has_and_belongs_to_many

   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   before_destroy { users.clear }
```

[docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

> 4.3.2.4 :dependent
>
> Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is
> destroyed:
>
> :destroy causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed
>
> :delete_all causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute) :nullify causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.
>
> :restrict_with_exception causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records
>
> :restrict_with_error causes an error to be added to the owner if there are any associated objects

Comment: Oh another thing, when I call Match.delete.all, only the entries in the Match table gets deleted, how do I extend this to also include the entries in the join table?

Comment: the before_destroy callback returns the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `before_destroy' for ActiveRecord:Module"

Comment: should work. make sure your class is extending 'ActiveRecord::Base' examples - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Scratch that, there is no errors now, but the join table is still not  cleared

Comment: how do you delete Match table record?

Comment: Right now I'm just testing in the rails console, but I call Match.delete_all

Comment: try deleting one Match using `Match.destroy(1)`

Comment: I get "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Match with id=1
"

Comment: I mean, add one Match record manually. and try deleting with destroy method and check the join table.

Comment: Okay I got it working now, my database data was a little out of sync.. It works when I call Match.destroy(x), but still, when I try to delete all matches at once, the join table remains untouched

Comment: try `destroy_all` instead of `delete_all`. it will delete the join table as well.